# Sails.js / waterline / sails-mysql: Saving milliseconds in a model datetime attribute

Tags: mysql, datetime, sails.js, waterline

I'm trying to save milliseconds of datetime objects in my DB. So far I managed to do that by replacing every `DATETIME` string with `DATETIME(3)` in `node_modules/sails-mysql/lib/adapter.js` `define` function. This is pretty hacky, though, and could cause issues when switching environments since I have `node_modules` in .gitignore.

So I was wondering: Is there a way to alter the MySQL schema in `config/bootstrap.js` or somewhere similar, e.g. in a smart kind of a place? Or do I just manually have to add the DATETIME -> DATETIME(3) conversion every time I swap to a new environment?

Comment: You are talking about separate field, not native Sails *createdAt* or *updateAt*?

Comment: Yeah, I mean a separate field. I solved my issue in another way, which let me keep the field as it is.

Comment: That's right, I wanted to suggest the same way. Also, in fact, Sails stores data in its local DB in ISO8601 format. But as for MySQL it stores in native Datetime string. So only separate fileds in integer to store Unix timestamp in milliseconds or fields as string to store ISO8601